# Java scanner with integers, stop this loop with empty line

Tags: java, loops, user-input

I have written this simple loop for collecting integers from the standard input.
How can I modify this loop, so that it stops when the user enters a blank line?
Right now the loop keeps going on, ignoring empty lines, it only stops when i insert a letter (for example).

I would like it to work both as a prompt, but also as a standard input redirect.

Thanks in advance.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class example{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        boolean auth = true;
        do {
            try{
                int num = in.nextInt();
                in.nextLine();
                System.out.println(num);
            } catch(Exception e){
                System.out.println(e);
                in.nextLine();
                auth = false;
            }
        } while(auth);
        in.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: What does "*I would like it to work both as a prompt, but also as a standard input redirect.*" mean?

Comment: See here for I/O redirecting in Java
https://chortle.ccsu.edu/java5/Notes/chap22/ch22_7.html

Comment: I know what is redirecting. I don't understand the quote which I've questioned. Besides, [your link](https://chortle.ccsu.edu/java5/Notes/chap22/ch22_7.html) doesn't say much about redirection of the I/O.

Comment: For some strange reason, I was unable to implement a solution with Scanner that worked both from command prompt (ie with user data entry), and with input redirect (ie reading from file).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `in.nextLine()` instead of `in.nextInt()`, and then use the `isEmpty()` function to check if it is empty and `Integer.parseInt()` to convert it back to an int. You can do it more efficiently but this should suffice

```
int num = 0;
String input = in.nextLine();
if(input.isEmpty()){
  auth = false;
}
else{
  num = Integer.parseInt(input);
  System.out.println(num);
}
```

Comment: You shall also put a try-catch block in this so that if someone enters a character or string value which is not a number, then it shall not show an error.

Answer (score -1):

Use next() instead of nextLine().
nextLine() reads inputs including the space between the words. A space will be read as empty String.
If you are using next(), it will not read blank lines at all. It reads the input till the space.